# Import Error from Matplotlib v. 2.2.2 under Anaconda 5.1 Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: python-3.x, macos, matplotlib

I've installed an application PyKep installed under the Anaconda distribution version 5.1 and in running a simple,

```
import pykep as pk
```

posted on https://esa.github.io/pykep/examples/ex1.html. The response I get is

> (pagmo) Samuels-Mac-Pro:~ user$ python
>   Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 13:44:09) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   import pykep as pk
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pykep/**init**.py", line 48, in 
>       from pykep import core, sims_flanagan, pontryagin, orbit_plots, examples, phasing, util, planet, trajopt
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pykep/pontryagin/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>       from ._leg import leg
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pykep/pontryagin/_leg.py", line 6, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 31, in 
>       import matplotlib.colorbar
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in 
>       import matplotlib.contour as contour
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 20, in 
>       import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
>     File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 55, in 
>       from matplotlib import afm, cbook, ft2font, rcParams, get_cachedir
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _inflateValidate
>     Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>    in /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/pagmo/lib/libpng16.16.dylib

I'm running this on a Mac Pro under Mac OS X ver. 10.12.6 Sierra, under Python 3.6.5. I'm running Matplotlib ver. 2.2.2.

It appears that I may have some misconfiguration with respect to Matplotlib with it invoking libz in /usr/lib as opposed to using the one under

> /Users/user/anaconda3/lib

.

Any suggestions?

Sam Dupree
P.S. - I'm still learning Python, so when it comes to solutions please keep it straightforwardly simple (my version of K.I.S.S.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to point `/Users/user/anaconda3/lib`.